# Dell Inspiron 7460 not turning on, battery LED flashing 2 amber, 7 white

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, troubleshooting, dell-inspiron

Dell Inspiron 7460 laptop isn't starting (keyboard light is up, but not appears in screen), wich makes me unable to run their diagnostics tool. Meanwhile, the battery LED is blinking in a 2 orange - 7 white pattern, and for some reason I'm unable to find what the LED code means (it's weird because I've found this kind of information for older models.).

I was able to turn on the computer a while ago, it seemed to work fine except for the LED blinking. I tried to ask in support, but it seems like they won't just tell what it means, but ask me to run the diagnostics tool.

Where can I find this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Your laptop's display assembly has failed.

Page 74 of the [Inspiron 14-7460 service manual](http://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/inspiron-14-7460-laptop_service%20manual_en-us.pdf) says this is an "LCD failure".

You'll need to get your computer repaired. If it's under warranty, you should send it in to Dell. Alternatively, you might be able to replace the display assembly yourself if you're sufficiently skilled and have the appropriate parts. The steps to do this are in page 34 of the service manual.